# How to read properties fragment from Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to read fragment of an array by @Value (Spring 5)?

Something like this:

Input
data.properties :

```
list.numbers=1,2,3
```

Read

```java
@Value("${list.numbers[0]}")
int firstNumber;
```

Output

```
firstNumber=1
```

Comment: No. I'm not reading array, but extract some value of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split and get the first element.

```java
@Value("#{'${list.numbers}'.split(',')[0]}")
int firstNumber;
```

Comment: Spring boot only

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago, I have used bean injection with XML configuration.
You can read [that blog article](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-inject-collections-using-list-element-in-spring/) and using `spring-core`, `spring-beans` and `spring-context-support` dependencies.

Below you'll find the XML config of that bean injection with the `<bean ref="beanListItemId">` (here : `song1`, `song2`, etc.) inside your bean list (here the list container is `album`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="song1" class="org.kodejava.spring.core.Song">
        <property name="title" value="I Saw Her Standing There" />
        <property name="writer" value="Beatles" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="song2" class="org.kodejava.spring.core.Song">
        <property name="title" value="Misery" />
        <property name="writer" value="Beatles" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="song3" class="org.kodejava.spring.core.Song">
        <property name="title" value="Anna (Go to Him)" />
        <property name="writer" value="Beatles" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="album" class="org.kodejava.spring.core.Album">
        <property name="title" value="Please Please Me" />
        <property name="year" value="1963" />
        <property name="songs">
            <list>
                <ref bean="song1" />
                <ref bean="song2" />
                <ref bean="song3" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```